# Retrieving info of a very large directory

Tags: php, linux, subdirectory

I hit Linux's 32,000 subdirectory limit.  It caused problems with my PHP scripts and I don't want it to happen again.

The simple solution is to have my PHP scripts check the current subdirectory count before trying to create another subdirectory.

All ideas I've seen to perform such a check involve iterating over the entire directory and counting every folder.  Considering my concern is with very large directories, is there a better way to retrieve the number of files/folders it contains?

Bonus question: is there also a non-iterative way to find the disk usage of a directory?

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Comment: The **du** command calculates the disk usage of a folder, although it probably searches through the entire folder to do so, it would still be faster than anything you can do in PHP. And **why do you have 32,000 subfolders???**

Comment: I'm almost positive your real problem is the fact that you have 32k folders, The limit is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way is to design your directory layout so there's no way you'll ever have 32000 files in a single directory.  In fact, I'd suggest that even 1000 files in a directory is too many.

The approach I usually take to this problem involves extra levels of directory hierarhy.  A typical way is to take the file names you're currently storing in a single directory and break it up into pieces that correspond to nested directories.  So, if you have a bunch of files like

```
xyzzy
foo
bar
blah
```

you might in fact store them as

```
x/xyzzy
f/foo
b/bar
b/blah
```

and so on.  You can extend this to multiple directory levels, or use more than one character to split the subdirectories, in order to trade off the depth versus breadth of this approach.

You'll probably get suggestions that you use a file system that doesn't have the 32k file limit.  Personally, even with such a file system, I would always use a scheme like I'm proposing here.  It's almost impossible to work effectively with command-line tools in directories with very very large numbers of files (even `ls` becomes entirely unwieldy), and  this sort of manual exploration is always needed during development, debugging, and often from time to time during normal operation.

Comment: Whoops!  I forgot to answer the bonus question: if by "non-iterative way to find the disk usage of a directory" you mean a way that doesn't involve looking at the size of every file in the directory, then the answer is no.

Comment: Dale - thanks.  My application requires that each user gets a directory, and I have more than 32000 users.  But let's say, as an extreme example, that I had 1,000,000 users - how could my filesystem ever really avoid large directories in that case?

Comment: More levels of hierarchy gives you exponential growth in the number of names you can store.  For example, 1000000 is 1000 squared.  Assuming alphabetic user names, 26^2 is 676, or roughly 1000, so you might consider file names like "us/er/user1", "us/er/user2", "xy/zz/xyzzy", "pl/ug/plugh", and so on.

Comment: I should add that this simple scheme as described is susceptible to an uneven distribution of names.  Ie, you've got a problem if every one of your million users chooses a name starting with "user".  You can address this by hashing the user names and creating the file names from the hash (note that git does this for its object storage).  Eventually, it's possible you'll want to consider a more complete database, although whether a key/value system like bdb or something sql-based would depend on how you want to manipulate and search your data.

Comment: I suppose you have some unique identifier of the user (e.g. ID) which is numeric? Then you can use it to format it like XXXXXXXX (for example first user would be 00000001) and you can split it in groups of two numbers: users/00/00/00/01/(user's stuff); users/01/12/32/41/(user's stuff). We use this algorithm for storing tons of images and it works nice for now.